# Can't locate airdrop files on Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, airdrop

I airdropped a big folder approx 33GB from Mac containing images and videos. But I can't locate them. My existing storage definitely increased by 33 gb - but can't locate that airdropped folder anywhere.

I checked and found if you don't have a supporting app the airdropped content won't open. But is it possible to maybe locate and delete this 33gb folder?

Comment: When you received the AirDrop, you should have gotten an alert asking where to open it. Did you? What did you choose.

Comment: Have you looked into the files app and checked in settings which app size increased (settings -> general -> iPhone-storage)?

Comment: I checked “system” has increased in iPhone storage

Comment: @elin didn’t get the option of selecting opening location. It was a big transfer so opened my iPhone after a while and nothing was prompting. But transfer did happen as my storage did increase by 33gb